# warn uninstall not installed for npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I downloaded and installed nodejs on Windows.  I'm trying to uninstall the version of typescript I have to get to an older version.  When I run

```
npm uninstall typescript
```

or

```
npm uninstall -g typescript
```

I get

```
npm warn uninstall not installed in C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules: "typescript@0.9.7"
```

How can I uninstall typescript without having npm uninstall work?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked whether typescript is actually there? npm uninstall typescript should work fine if you're in the project's folder. Maybe the name of the module isn't exactly typescript?

Comment: @lascort when I try `npm view typescript version`, it says 0.9.7.  Is it installed in the node_modules folder?

Comment: @lascort When I try to uninstall anre inerstall 0.9.5, it looks like it grabs the 0.9.5 version.  But when I use the version command again, it still says 0.9.7.

Comment: this might be a strange suggestion but have you tried 'npm unbuild typescript' ??

Answer (score 1):

You should have been able to uninstall typescript with the command

```
npm rm typescript
npm rm -g typescript
```

which is equivalent to `uninstall`.  If that doesn't work, it is safe to find the `typescript` directory in Windows Explorer under `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules` and remove it.

This should get you to a state with no typescript installed:

```
npm ls typescript
npm ls -g typescript
```

both show `(empty)`.

Second point: `npm view typescript version` is not showing you information about your local setup, but rather the state of the `npm` repository, so it will always show you the version that corresponds to `typescript@latest`.  At the time you asked this question, it was 0.9.7; it is now 1.3.0

Finally: to install a specific version of typescript such as 0.9.5, do

```
npm install -g typescript@0.9.5
```

Also, in general, you should make sure you have the latest `node` and `npm`.  Updating `npm` on windows is a little tricky; you should follow the guide here: https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows